# Are there any animals that maintain white fur year round?

Tags: zoology, environment

Besides examples of rare albino animals, it seems animals only have white fur during the winter.  Additionally, and not coincidentally, the examples I've found live in the northern latitudes with predicable snow cover and have different colored coats in the summer months.  **Are there any examples of animals that maintain a white coat of fur year round**, or are there simply no environments that such a trait would be beneficial in?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep :)

Comment: [White Cats](https://www.catster.com/lifestyle/albino-cat-kitten-health-facts-what-is-albinism-siamese-cats)

Comment: Relatedly (but not fur), all-white colouration is not restricted to animals that experience snow. Consider the white tern, a tropical seabird. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_tern.

Comment: Are you asking about only wild animals?  Because there are numerous domestic animal varieties that have breeds that are white.  There's also the white tiger: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_tiger  And then there's the old argument about the zebra: is it white with black stripes, or vice versa?

Comment: @jamesqf: Yes, only wild animals.  Sorry, I should have been more explicit in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Polar bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_bear) (*Ursus maritimus*) have white fur all year long.

[image]
[image]

There are probably several other examples. @L.Diago gave sheep as example. There are also all white troglodyte species.

Comment: This may be splitting hairs so to speak but the fur of a polar bear is actually transparent and gives off a white color due to reflection of snow. https://polarbearfacts.net/why-are-polar-bears-white/

Comment: @wanderweeer It is actually a good point. I have never been able to fully understand the polar bear fur but I would note that on the second picture, on a green background, the polar bear still look white.

Comment: @wanderweeer: That explanation seems a bit confused. As Remi.b says, a polar bear can have fur that will still look whitish even when there is no snow around. The fur is (more or less) colorless and scatters the ambient light, so it looks whitish. Many "white" objects/substances are built of smaller parts that are somewhat translucent or transparent; e.g. [salt](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66356/why-is-sodium-chloride-white) and [snow](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/why-is-snow-white)

Comment: @Remi.b: I think it's closer to being blue and black tbh

Comment: @Remi.b & sumelic: I wish I knew more about how the lack of pigmentation in the polar bear hair works optically and I'd agree that it has more to due with scattering the ambient light than it's surroundings.  I don't ever remembering hearing a similar explanation for the white fur of other arctic animals.